# Obstacle rotation

Tags: rotation, netlogo

So the obstacle in the program was defined as follow:

```
to-report patch-rect [x y dw dh] ;; report patch set centered at x y and dw dh 
                                    around x y
report patches with [pxcor >= x - dw and pxcor <= x + dw and pycor >= y - dh and pycor <= y + dh]"
```

The agents (ants) in my program would interact with this obstacle, rotate the obstacle in order to reduce their path length to the sink. Is there anyway I can do this? How do I specify their rotation based on the point and angle of contact? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "rotate the obstacle".